# Open a Python program with a subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to open a python file on my Windows computer with a subprocess, but I can't make it work.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('python C:\Users\Kristian\Desktop\Python\Ja\Bakkom var her.py',shell=True)
```

This is my code. when I run it I get a window on my screen saying:

> (unicode error)'unicodeescape' codec can´t decode bytes in position
>   9-10: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: add an r in front of the filename string

Comment: Then it will ignore all the \s which normally signal special operators inside a string (`r'string'` is called a raw string)

Comment: you should escape the backslash chars as two : `\\'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [famous problem with Windows](http://blog.lerner.co.il/avoiding-windows-backslash-problems-with-pythons-raw-strings/), since it uses [backslashes instead of forward](https://www.howtogeek.com/181774/why-windows-uses-backslashes-and-everything-else-uses-forward-slashes/) as file delimiters. Python is trying to parse text preceded by `\U` (as in 'Users') as a Unicode character, which it isn't.

You can work around it by:

- using double-slashes (`'python C:\\Users\\Kristian\\Desktop\\Python\\Ja\\Bakkom var her.py'`)
- using forward-slashes (`'python C:/Users/Kristian/Desktop/Python/Ja/Bakkom var her.py'`)
- prepending `r` to indicate raw text. (`r'python C:\Users\Kristian\Desktop\Python\Ja\Bakkom var her.py'`)